# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 'geckodriver' when trying to open firefox using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/bin/geckodriver")
browser.get('http://www.ubuntu.com/')
```

The entire stack trace looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 160, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
stdin=PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 'geckodriver'
```

my path to geckodriver is:

```
/usr/bin/geckodriver
```

And selenium is in:

```
selenium in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (3.12.0)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have most probably installed a version of geckodriver that is meant for a different OS/platform! get the correct version from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and replace the one you have.

Comment: Yes, because the thing you have is not recognised as a valid executable by the OS! It's like trying to run a .exe on Linux!

Comment: yes, I installed the arm version instead of Linux by mistake.As explain in this link https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63258/selenium-firefox-oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error

Comment: Yup same problem here, tried to install the Linux version on a Mac. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to install the latest chrome driver which supports selenium:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```