# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error with GeckoDriver and Selenium on MacOS

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am using firefox gecko driver to make a bot, I keep getting error messages with my bot and I have found that the source of the message is the:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser= webdriver.Firefox()
```

lines.

I have added every file mentioned in the error message to path including gecko driver, firefox, and the other smaller documents. I am at a complete loss

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/fuckobot1.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser= webdriver.Firefox()

File "/Users/'myname'/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()

File "/Users/'myname'/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child

raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Comment: This is probably happened due to using an executable that is not meant for your operation system, which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using MacOS Sierra version 10.12.6

Comment: And which executables are you using?

Comment: i am using geckodriver version 0.23.0

Comment: im very sorry, im a beginner that bit off more than he could chew by promising a friend that he would help him with a bot.

Comment: Do you need geckodriver? You can download the chromedrive and use this line of code `driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')` 
http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started`

Comment: I already have the developer codes

Comment: sorry what i meant was i have the URL codes(from inspect element) of the website i am using on firefox, and i need to finish this code by wednesday so unless the inspect element codes are a constant, i cant make the switch

Comment: The driver should not change the rest of the code.

Comment: i understand that but I have search element codes in which i use specific spots of a page in order to buy an item. the codes are not interchangeable between chrome and firefox

Comment: is there anything i can do without changing my webdriver

Comment: Try confirming it with another tool possibly like [katalon](https://www.katalon.com/) and a basic test to open the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSError: \[Errno 8\] Exec format error: 'geckodriver' when trying to open firefox using selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662674/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-geckodriver-when-trying-to-open-firefox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** binary which was invoked was not in proper format.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** of the **GeckoDriver** binary format with respect to the underlying *Operating System*.

As you are on **MacOS** you need to download **geckodriver-v0.23.0-macos.tar.gz** from [mozilla/geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), untar/unzip it and provide the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* through the argument **`executable_path`** as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser= webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
```

Comment: i do have annother small problem, I put geckodriver into path but i still get the error message                                                                                                                              'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: Im not entirely sure what that means. please clarify.

Comment: @PYANNANANA I meant can you raise a new question along with the trace logs please?

Comment: i tried, but I am at my limit for some reason, I've asked too many. stack overflow will not let me

Comment: please help, im not sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

This may be answer to this issue,
when it shows something like, Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.
Actual problem is, Firefox 48.0 or greater not works with selenium 3.0.0 or greater version.
so please check your versions. 
so, to make it work you need to update with recent selenium and respective geckodriver version too that fixes this issue.

then try basic commands,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```