# Errno 8 EXEC Format Error using geckodriver 28 on FF 81 Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have 3 lines of code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= './geckodriver')
driver.get('http://wikipedia.org')
```

Whenever I run this, line 2 gives the error:

> [Errno 8] Exec format error './geckodriver'

I've tried the following 64-bit geckodrivers 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, and 28
Ubuntu loaded Firefox 81.0.2 (64-bit)

So far, no dice.

This code works in my Windows environment with geckodriver 27 and Firefox 84.

Is there a trick to making it work on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
[Errno 8] Exec format error './geckodriver'
```

...implies that the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) binary which was invoked was not in the required format.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453) binary format with respect to the underlying *Operating System*.

As you are on **Ubuntu** you need to download the latest **geckodriver-v0.28.0-linux64.tar.gz** from [mozilla/geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), untar/unzip it and provide the *absolute path* of the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073748/which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-3-6-0/47095220#47095220) through the argument **`executable_path`** as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser= webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error with GeckoDriver and Selenium on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808760/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-with-geckodriver-and-selenium-on-macos/52810095#52810095)

Comment: It turns out that the GeckoDriver I was using has issues with Ubuntu on a RaspberryPi 4.