# Selenium Library dont work correctly (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, thonny

After a long break of programming I wanted to start again with selenium.
I have installed the newest version and I placed the geckodriver executable in PATH, but theres a error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 'geckodriver
```

And my script is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

I searched very long now but dont found anything. I hope some1 can help me.

Max

EDIT: I fixed it on my own by using `sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver`

Thanks for the guy in te comments for help

Comment: Have you downloaded the geckodriver from the official  (git) page : https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases ? Your code is fine. You have must downlaod the wrong geckodriver file (os or version).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: \[Errno 8\] Exec format error: 'geckodriver' when trying to open firefox using selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662674/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-geckodriver-when-trying-to-open-firefox)

Comment: @MariosKaramanis No it dont answer my question. I checked if I downloaded the right version but It was the correct one.  I placed the geckodriver file in  '/usr/bin/' but it dont work

Comment: @MariosKaramanis btw I think theres no geckodriver file for arm architectures. If there are, please let me know