# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 'geckodriver'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi3, geckodriver

I have a raspberry pi 3 with Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) as Os.
Trying to lunch a python file that use selenium and i'm getting all these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/fabb/Documents/prog/main.py", line 26, in <module>
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=opt)
File "/home/fabb/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 172, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/home/fabb/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1823, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 'geckodriver'
```

i did these steps to install geckodriver:

```
tar -xzvf geckodriver-v0.34.0-linux32.tar.gz 
sudo cp geckodriver /usr/bin/
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: \[Errno 8\] Exec format error: 'geckodriver' when trying to open firefox using selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662674/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-geckodriver-when-trying-to-open-firefox)